# Why redux store deletes when click on <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, persist

I want to replace the `<a>` tag element with something else if possible in such a way to be able to keep the redux store. I tried Link or NavLink but it is not working. I want to keep the redux store without a persistent feature.

My app works fine on all screens without a persistent store but when I click on a `<a>` tag the store is deleted and I have to login back.

Comment: if you need to save data on browser, use [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist)

Answer (score 0):

Redux store lives in memory, so if you refresh the page its gone. You can use a router library like React Router to navigate through your SPA without actually refreshing the page